# Calling a function twice but in second time, first list which was returned by the function goes as argument in python

Tags: python, matrix, memory-management, function-call

in function entery when the first time argument is going (n, a) it's working fine a goes as empty list initialized with 0. but in the second time when b matrix is going as argument (n, b), so at that time li list which was returned by the function before is going as matrix b rather than empty matrix b which was initialized by 0. someone please help me finding error in my code.

```
#funtion for taking input in matrix
def entery(n, li):
    print(li)
    print('enter the element of matrix: ')
    for a in range(n):
        for b in range(n):
            no = int(input())
            li[a][b]= no
    return li #returning the updated matrix

n = int(input('dimensions of square matrix:'))
a = []
c = []
result = []
#creating matrix
for i in range(n):
    b =[]
    for j in range(n):
        b.append(0)
    a.append(b)
    c.append(b)
    result.append(b)

print("a matrix",a)
print("c matrix",c)
fm = []
sm = []
#calling function
fm = entery(n,a)
sm = entery(n,c)

print(fm)
print(sm)
#addition of matrix
for x in range(n):
    for y in range(n):
        result[x][y] = fm[x][y] + sm[x][y]

print(result)
```

the output is shown below-

```
output:
dimensions of square matrix:2
a matrix [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
c matrix [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
[[0, 0], [0, 0]] #when called first time
enter the element of matrix: 
11
22
33
44
[[11, 22], [33, 44]] # but in second time...
enter the element of matrix: 
12 
23
34
45
[[12, 23], [34, 45]]
[[12, 23], [34, 45]]
[[24, 46], [68, 90]]
```

Answer (score 1):

All parameters (arguments) in the `Python` language are `passed by reference`. It means if you change what a parameter refers to within a `function`, the change also reflects back in the calling function.

---

So when you pass a `mutable list` like `a` to the function, there is a chance that the `a` list to get changed, like in the `entry()` function which you're inserting numbers to the list.

However if you check the value of list `c` after the first function call, you'll notice that it has been changed ,too.

```py
[...]
#calling function
fm = entery(n,a)
print(f"a: {a}")
print(f"c: {c}")
[...]
```

result:

```py
dimensions of square matrix:2
a matrix [[0, 0], [0, 0]]    
c matrix [[0, 0], [0, 0]]    
[[0, 0], [0, 0]]
enter the element of matrix: 
11
22
33
44
a: [[11, 22], [33, 44]]
c: [[11, 22], [33, 44]]
```

**The reason is that:**
There is a reference between `a` and `c`. When you first initialized both `a` and `c`, you put same list `b` in both lists:

```py
[...]
for i in range(n):
    b =[]
    for j in range(n):
        b.append(0)
    a.append(b)       # <------
    c.append(b)       # <------
    result.append(b)
[...]
```

As you know `b` is also a list so when you put it in both `a` and `c` lists, the lists in "`a` and `c` lists" will have same `id`s and `reference`s, therefor if we change one of those lists, the other will be also changed.

---

You can prevent this, by using a copy of `b` when initiating the `a` and `c` lists, like this:

```py
#creating matrix
for i in range(n):
    b =[]
    for j in range(n):
        b.append(0)
    a.append(b[:])    # <---- This makes a copy of list "b"
    c.append(b[:])
    result.append(b[:])
```

**Therefor the result will be:**

```py
dimensions of square matrix:2
a matrix [[0, 0], [0, 0]]    
c matrix [[0, 0], [0, 0]]    
[[0, 0], [0, 0]]
enter the element of matrix: 
11
22
33
44
[[0, 0], [0, 0]]
enter the element of matrix:
12
23
34
45
[[11, 22], [33, 44]]
[[12, 23], [34, 45]]
[[23, 45], [67, 89]]
```